# how to remove the black border in the toggle button when appeared in it is clicked?

Tags: toggle, navbar, bootstrap-5

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHX7k.jpg)

I tried to remove that black border that appear when I clicked the toggle button, but I can`t find the solution, I`m using bootstrap5, please give me a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use **"shadow-none"** class on button and it will remove it.